# Generate Managed Class from WMI in Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, wmi

I have a solution where I spiked a cusom WMI management class.  I created a management class, registered the assembly using installutil, generated the management component through server explore and all was well.  I'm now pushing a real implementation into my code base.  I've done all of the same things but when I try to "Generate Managed Class" as in the picture below, the menu item is disabled.

[image: disabled]

If I try to do this ***in any other VS solution***, pointing to the exact same object in WMI, the menu option is enabled.

I can't seem to find an answer. The problem is obviously somewhere in this particular solution.  I'm not sure where to look.

Thanks.

-Joe

Comment: Can you post the .sln?